# OpenFileDialog reads only the first file

Tags: c#, streamreader, openfiledialog

I'm using the following code to open multiple XML files and read the contents of the files but it doesn't work.

```
OpenFD.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml)|*.xml";
OpenFD.Multiselect = true;

if (OpenFD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    foreach (string file in OpenFD.FileNames)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(file);

        System.IO.Stream fileStream = OpenFD.OpenFile();
        System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileStream);
        using (streamReader)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
        }
        fileStream.Close();
    }
}
```

For testing purposes, I created two xml files.

- file1.xml (its content is "string1")
- file2.xml (its content is "string2")

When I open the dialog and select the two files, I get four messages.

- file1.xml
- string1
- file2.xml
- string1

Even though the OpenFileDialog reads the file names correctly, I can't get to read the second file. It only reads the first file. So I'm guessing the problem is related to StreamReader, not to OpenFileDialog. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `OpenFD.OpenFile()` in each iteration, [which](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.openfile(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Opens the file selected by the user, [...] specified by the **FileName** property.

[Which in turn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx):

> can only be the name of **one selected file**.

Use the `file` variable from your loop instead, and the [`StreamReader` constructor that accepts a string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ke0fzy(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file))
{
    MessageBox.Show(streamReader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This line is opening the file from the OpenFileDialog:

```
System.IO.Stream fileStream = OpenFD.OpenFile();
```

But there's no specification for which file. You need a way to distinguish which file you're opening.  I would get rid of that line all together and just use the string file you have in the loop.

```
System.IO.StreamReader streamReader = new System.IO.StreamReader(file);
```