# Process multiple selected files from OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, sql-server, filestream

I used foreach loop for reading multiple image files but I am able to only stream first selected file.When I try to save multiple different images, outputs are like exact copies of the first selected image instead of remaining different images.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBHandler.GetConnectionString());
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog fop = new OpenFileDialog();
            fop.Multiselect = true;

            fop.InitialDirectory = "C:\\";
            fop.Filter = "JPG,JPEG|*.jpg|PNG|*png";
            if (fop.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                foreach (String files in fop.FileNames)
                {
                    FileStream FS = new FileStream(@fop.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    byte[] img = new byte[FS.Length];
                    FS.Read(img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(FS.Length));

                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveImage", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

                MessageBox.Show("Image has been saved successfully!!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```

I want to see all images on the same form.

My expectation: **A-B-C-D** *(each letter represents different retrieved images. "A" is the first selected file from dialog box)*

Actual output: **A-A-A-A**. Why does that happen?

Comment: Some advice on your code. Your SqlConnection should be in a using(). I'd recommend the same for the FileStream, or at the very least all FS.Close() when you're done. You don't want to leave resources allocated unnecessarily.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your loop, you're using [`fop.FileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filename(v=vs.110).aspx), which returns the first selected file:

> This property can only be the name of one selected file. If you want to return an array containing the names of all selected files in a multiple-selection dialog box, use FileNames.

```
foreach (String files in fop.FileNames)
{
    FileStream FS = new FileStream(@fop.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    // ...
}
```

Change it instead to use the iteration variable `filename`:

```
foreach (String filename in fop.FileNames)
{
    FileStream FS = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

    // ...
}
```

Related: [OpenFileDialog reads only the first file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31186376/openfiledialog-reads-only-the-first-file/31186446#31186446).

Comment: oops I have just realised I have mistyped your solution.There is no error sorry for inconvenience :) + thank you for your help.  was trying to use dialogbox itself to place in loop. it seems totally silly :)

Answer (score -1):

your code should be like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(DBHandler.GetConnectionString());
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog fop = new OpenFileDialog();
            fop.Multiselect = true;

            fop.InitialDirectory = @"C:\";
            fop.Filter = "JPG,JPEG|*.jpg|PNG|*png";
            if (fop.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {

                foreach (String files in fop.FileNames)
                {
                    FileStream FS = new FileStream(@files, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                    byte[] img = new byte[FS.Length];
                    FS.Read(img, 0, Convert.ToInt32(FS.Length));

                    if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                        con.Open();
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveImage", con);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.Add("@img", SqlDbType.Image).Value = img;
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

                MessageBox.Show("Image has been saved successfully!!", "Information", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }
```

Comment: By dumping "fixed" code you aren't helping anyone learn anything. Explain what problem you saw, what causes that and how you fixed it. Also try to click the "New answers" bar before posting to see if you aren't posting duplicate content.

Comment: sure i will take care of that in future.thanks @CodeCaster.